# Trouble with 2004 rodeo clutch

Tags: clutch, bleeding, isuzu, rodeo, hydraulic-pressure

I have a 2004 rodeo and the clutch went soft the other day and no longer has any pressure in it. 
I have  changed out the slave cylinder,
Checked the master cylinder 
Check all lines for leakage
Have not touched  the damper as not sure what it actually does. 
Have bled the system manually by opening bleeder pushing down pedal, closing bleeder and releasing clutch and repeted until no air visible. 
Have also bled it with the use of pressure
Im still getting no pressure on the clutch and im all out of ideas now is there any little tricks or things im missing to why this is still not working? 
Thank you 
Bianca

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have someone look at the soft parts of the hydraulic line as you press the clutch pedal. It could be it has lost integrity and is bulging as the pedal gets pressed, yet is going back to normal after release and doesn't show signs of leaking/bulging.

Answer (score 0):

From most of the above I'd say it's the master cylinder piston. There will be no outside leak, but it will not generate normal pressure (but may still have enough to bleed the system). 
Also, there are no flex lines in that system if I remember correctly, so nothing will "bulge". 
My guess would be replace the MC.